# How do I query an Entitlement Process through Apex

Tags: apex, query, entitlements

I'm trying to query an entitlement process with a specific name to dynamically assign it to an account based on certain criteria. I can't seem to get the query correct. I googled around and the object is supposed to be EntitlementProcess but it doesn't seem to work.

My query looks like this:

```
EntitlementProcess sla =[Select id from EntitlementProcess Where Name='SLA Tracx'];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual Object name to access from API is `SlaProcess` and in UI it is `EntitlementProcess`

```
SELECT Id, description, name From SlaProcess Where Name='SLA Tracx'
```

Ideally Account will linked with Entitlement and Entitlement is linked with SlaProcess (aka EntitlementProcess).

So your query to get AccountId based on Entitlement and SlaProcess will be:

```
SELECT AccountId, Name 
FROM Entitlement 
WHERE SlaProcessId IN (
    SELECT Id 
    From SlaProcess 
    Where Name='SLA Tracx')
```